# Numpy: Compute dot product of 2d arrays with a condition before summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem where I have two arrays with dimensions
*n x d* and *d x h*, where *n*, *d*, and *h* are positive integers that may or may not be the same. I am trying to find the dot product of the two matrices but with the condition that for each multiplication, I apply a function *g* to the term.

For example, in a case where *n*=2, *d*=3, and *h*=3
If I had the following matrices:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 5, 6]]

b = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [1, 1, 1]]
```

I would want to find *c* such that

```
c = [[g(1*1)+g(2*4)+g(3*1), g(1*2)+g(2*5)+g(3*1), g(1*3)+g(2*6)+g(3*1)],
     [g(4*1)+g(5*4)+g(6*1), g(4*2)+g(5*5)+g(6*1), g(4*3)+g(5*6)+g(6*1)]]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What would be the function you are planning to include? Is it ok to also post it here? Thank you

Comment: The sigmoid function 
g(x) = 1/(1 + exp(-x))

Comment: A `dot` is equivalent to something like  `(a[:,None,:]* b[:,None]).sum(axis=1)`.  That is expand the dimensions so they broadcast and do elementwise multiply., then sum the 'shared' dimension.  You could apply your function before the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by first doing the multiplications with broadcasting, applying `g()`, and then summing across the correct axis:

```py
import numpy as np


def g(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6]])


b = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [1, 1, 1]])
```

First, the multiplication `a[:, None] * b.T` (probably a nicer way to do this), then evaluate `g(x)`, then sum across axis 2:

```py
>>> g(a[:, None] * b.T).sum(axis=2)
array([[2.68329736, 2.83332581, 2.90514211],
       [2.97954116, 2.99719203, 2.99752123]])
```

Verifying that the first row indeed matches your desired result:

```py
>>> g(1*1) + g(2*4) + g(3*1)
2.683297355321972

>>> g(1*2) + g(2*5) + g(3*1)
2.8333258069316134

>>> g(1*3) + g(2*6) + g(3*1)
2.9051421094702645
```

Comment: This is already a clean code

Comment: Thanks! I enjoy numpy puzzles. Takes quite a bit of fiddling but I can usually find a way there :)

Comment: (I say 'puzzle' because I still don't quite grok broadcasting)